# Eclipse SVN Commits Partially Despite Conflict?

Tags: java, svn, eclipse-plugin

Through my experience, if one commits Java files through Eclipse utilizing the SVN plugin and encounters a merge conflict (by forgetting to update first), the plug goes ahead and commits *some* of the files before it encountered this conflict.

To me this seems like a real problem if you wish to preserve the build and want to be careful when checking things in.  Is this a preference option, or just intended behavior?  Thanks

Comment: That doesn't happen for me. Commits leading to a merge conflict are atomically not performed. I use Tortoise SVN, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, it's the intended behavior. Happened to me that already.
Also, the same goes when you update. It updates the other files while you need to do some operation on the conflict.

Moreover, there's no configuration in the preferences where you can opt anything related to conflict and merge.

HIH.